# Can a WebForms class be used to call a wcf (within the same .net .sln) service function?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, webforms

We have a .net v4.5.1 solution (.sln) that contains a WebForms project and a WCF project.  This was set up to "prove" or "test" the wcf service.  The wcf function that does the work takes in a parameter of List(Of clsREC_TaskParam). I have declared all of the DataContract and DataMembers in the wcf code files.  The 'clsREC_TaskParam' is a complex class that contains a number of other complex classes.  The wcf wsdl reflects these complex classes as expected.

This wcf service is intended to be non-public, but to be used as a background task for the WebForms application so as to NOT hang up the page during the long-process of the WCF-service.

The same class code-file (containing all of these classes) is contained in each project.

The problem??? Question???

When I call the service from a button-click as follows:

```
  Dim bRet As Boolean = False
  Dim oSrvc = New GenPDFService.GenPDFServiceClient
  m_lstTaskParams = CType(Session("clsTask01"), List(Of clsREC_TaskParam))
  bRet = oSrvc.GenPDFs(m_lstTaskParams)
```

The compiler indicates on the last code line, that

> Error  1   Value of type '1-dimensional array of clsREC_TaskParam' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of GenPDFService.clsREC_TaskParam' because 'clsREC_TaskParam' is not derived from 'GenPDFService.clsREC_TaskParam'.

This confuses me, since I thought the WebForm class parameter (or wcf return-object) can be serialized for a .Net to .Net wcf service-call.

Your comments and solutions are welcome...thanks.

Comment: Are the namespaces in the both projects the same?  I.e., `Namespace1.MyClass` will not be viewed as the same as `Namespace2.MyClass`, even if the code is exactly the same.

Comment: I tried this in each of the two projects and got many errors like this...>Error class 'clsREC_TaskParam' and class 'clsREC_TaskParam', declared in 'C:\visual studio 2012\Projects\GenPDFService\GenPDFService\App_Code\clsREC_TaskParam.vb', conflict in namespace 'nsWcfGenPDFService'.

Comment: The solution to fixing the above errors is to rename all of my classes between the webforms-project and the wcf-project. -- any comments?